# PR2 motor control GUI/interface

Tags: ros, pr2, teleoperation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

I've been looking around for an easy-to-use GUI-like interface to control joint angles of the PR2, like we have for iCub.

Do you know any tool that can be used in this manner?

Thanks in advance.

[image: iCub]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10834/pr2-motor-control-gui/interface/) by [Kadir Firat Uyanik](https://answers.ros.org/users/81/kadir-firat-uyanik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 288 on 2011-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have implemented an interface to control all the joints in Python. You can find it [here](http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?name=pr2_control_gui). It lacks documentation (we will fix that) but it is very feature rich.

At the moment you can:

- Control all the joints or just a subset of them
- Save a joints configuration on a file to retrieve it later
- Save a sequence of joints poses to execute in order

Please let me know if you need any help with the interface or if you have any feature request / problem.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) with karma: 1342 on 2011-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3